# Area of Kerr-Newman event horizon

Tags: black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, event-horizon, kerr-newman-metric

I want to calculate the area of event horizon for a [Kerr-Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) black hole by using boyer's coordinates.

I searched a lot from web, but I could not find any information about calculating event horizon radius for kerr newman. Can anyone help me to find any information, or help me how to calculate ?

Comment: Is the question about how to calculate a radius, or how to calculate an area? A radius would be kind of meaningless, since it's coordinate-dependent.

Comment: Yes, my main goal is area.

Comment: I think I managed to calculate it. If there is anyone who wonders how, I can write the answer here.

Comment: I would like to see how you did the integral.

Comment: It would be best to provide an answer if you have one so that you can close the question formally.  It will stop the system having yet another open-forever question on it.

Comment: I've done the integral and will write an answer.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the integral is trivial. I didn't notice at first that the coefficient of the cosine term in the square root is zero on the event horizon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In geometrical-Gaussian units with $G$, $c$, and $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ equal to 1, the Kerr-Newman metric for a black hole of mass $M$, angular momentum $J=aM$, and charge $Q$ is

$$\begin{align}
ds^2=
&-\left(1-\frac{2Mr-Q^2}{r^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\right)dt^2
+\frac{r^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}{r^2-2Mr+a^2+Q^2}dr^2\\
&+(r^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta)}\,d\theta^2
+\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{a^2(2Mr-Q^2)\sin^2{\theta}}{r^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\right)\sin^2{\theta}\,d\phi^2\\
&-\frac{2a(2Mr-Q^2)\sin^2{\theta}}{r^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\,dt\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$. (When $Q$ is zero, this reduces to Wikipedia’s form for the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric). Wikipedia’s form for the [Kerr-Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) metric is equivalent to the above, but seems less straightforward.)

The $g_{rr}$ component of the metric tensor is infinite when the denominator
$r^2-2Mr+a^2+Q^2$ is zero. This happens at two radial coordinates,

$$r_\pm=m\pm\sqrt{m^2-a^2-Q^2}.$$

The event horizon is at $r_+$. We want to find the area of this surface. The 2D metric on the surface $t=$ constant and $r=r_+$ is

$$ds_+^2=
(r_+^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta)}\,d\theta^2
+\left(r_+^2+a^2+\frac{a^2(2Mr_+-Q^2)\sin^2{\theta}}{r_+^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\right)\sin^2{\theta}\,d\phi^2$$

and the area element on this surface is

$$\begin{align}
dA_+&=\sqrt{\det{g_+}}\,d\theta\,d\phi\\
&=\sqrt{(r_+^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta})\left(r_+^2+a^2+\frac{a^2(2Mr_+-Q^2)\sin^2{\theta}}{r_+^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta}}\right)}\sin{\theta}\,d\theta\,d\phi\\
&=\sqrt{(r_+^2+a^2\cos^2{\theta})(r_+^2+a^2)+a^2(2Mr_+-Q^2)(1-\cos^2{\theta})}\sin{\theta}\,d\theta\,d\phi\\
&=\sqrt{(r_+^4+a^2r_+^2+2Ma^2r_+-a^2Q^2)+a^2(r_+^2-2Mr_++a^2+Q^2)\cos^2{\theta}}\sin{\theta}\,d\theta\,d\phi.
\end{align}$$

Conveniently, the coefficient of $\cos^2{\theta}$ in the square root vanishes by the definition of $r_+$,

$$r_+^2-2Mr_++a^2+Q^2=0,$$

and, using this equation to eliminate $M$ in the first term in the square root, what's left under the square root becomes the perfect square $(r_+^2+a^2)^2$. Thus the area element simplifies to the trivial-to-integrate

$$dA_+=(r_+^2+a^2)\sin{\theta}\,d\theta\,d\phi.$$

Integrating over $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and over $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives the area of the event horizon,

$$A_+=4\pi(r_+^2+a^2)=4\pi\left(2M^2-Q^2+2M\sqrt{M^2-a^2-Q^2}\right).$$

Comment: I did exactly the same way and found same answer. Thank you so much for writing the answer!

Comment: @AliOz Would you like to mark it as accepted? If so, thanks.